# Flutter Stack: how to place items at the bottom

Tags: flutter

I have the following widget `StackedIcons`

```
reuturn Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
              CircleAvatar(), Positioned(left: 15, child: PlusOne())
          ]),
    );
```

which I want right aligned inside another widget

```
   Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [StackedIcons(match: match)]
   )
```

and this is what I get

[image]

This looks good in terms of what I want to achieve (the plus one on top of the user avatar). However it overflows the parent container.

If I use `right` offset for positioned the order of the icons will be inverted and I don't want that.

If possible I would like to specify to `Stack` place the element below the current one (rather than on top).

The output I want is to have this widget rigth aligned without going over the padding of the parent. If I remove the `Clip.none` behaviour I get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution might be to place your `PlusOne` inside the green `Container`, and then give the `Avatar` some offset on the right instead.

```dart
return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
              Positioned(right: 15, child: CircleAvatar()), 
              PlusOne(),
          ]),
    );
```

I'm not sure how this would affect things if you were to have multiple avatars and then the plus icon, but if you haven't tried this, it might work for you.